# Changing values in a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to loop through this array to change the column value:

```
array
  0 => null
  1 => 
    array
       'condition' => 
         array
          'column' => string 'data' (length=12)
          'operator' => string '=' (length=1)
          'argvalue' => string '442' (length=3)
   2 => 
    array
      'condition' => 
        array
          'column' => string 'start' (length=5)
          'operator' => string '>=' (length=2)
          'argvalue' => string '2013-11-21 00:00:00' (length=19)
   3 => 
    array
      'condition' => 
        array
          'column' => string 'start' (length=5)
          'operator' => string '<=' (length=2)
          'argvalue' => string '2013-11-21 23:59:59' (length=19)
   4 => null
```

Here's my code, whilst I can access $secondLevelIndex['column'] I don't seem to be able to change the value.

```
foreach ($created as $firstLevelIndex => $firstLevelArray) {
  foreach ($firstLevelArray as $secondLevelIndex) {
    //echo $secondLevelIndex['column'];
    $created[$firstLevelIndex][$secondLevelIndex]['column'] = 100;
  }
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it.

```
foreach ($created as $firstLevelIndex => $firstLevelArray) {
  foreach ($firstLevelArray as $secondLevelIndex => $secondLevelArray) {
    //echo $secondLevelIndex['column'];
    $created[$firstLevelIndex][$secondLevelIndex]['column'] = 100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach ($created as $firstLevelIndex => $firstLevelArray) {
  foreach ($firstLevelArray as $secondLevelIndex => $firstLevelArray) {
    //echo $secondLevelIndex['column'];
    $created[$firstLevelIndex][$secondLevelIndex]['column'] = 100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
foreach ($created as $firstLevelIndex => $firstLevelArray) {
  foreach ($firstLevelArray as $secondLevelIndex=>$value) {
    //echo $secondLevelIndex['column'];
    $created[$firstLevelIndex][$secondLevelIndex]['column'] = 100;
  }
}
```